# Chrome extension distributed through Chrome store not autoupdating

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension is distributed through the Chrome store, which is supposed to manage the auto-update itself and push it after a few hours to my users.

I pushed an update more than one week ago and it seems that is hasn't been pushed to any user. The Chrome store is displaying the latest version number, but browsers are just not updating.

I know how to force my browser to update but I want the update to push to all my users.

Is there any thing I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you _published_ the update's draft?

Comment: Yes, I published it. The correct latest version appears in the Chrome Store, as well as the last published date. But nothing update...

Comment: You could try publishing another update with just a version bump. It could be that some glitch happened and a new update will fix it.

Comment: how are you detecting your users arn't being updated?   It takes somewhere between a few days and a week for 99% of my 5000 users to update to the most recent version.  That happens because chrome must either be updated manually, or restarted for extensions to update.